# Specialization of template class method C++

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I have a generic linked list class `LList<T>` with a `LList<T>::insert()` method for inserting a sorted Node. I would like to specialize the `insert()` function to have different sorting when the type is `std::string`, but I get an error:

> LINK1169 "one or more multiply defined symbols found"

Below is the relevant code which yields that error:

LinkedList.h

```
template<typename T>
class LList
{
private:
    struct LLNode
    {
        //node code
    };
    LLNode* head, * tail;
public:
    LList<T>() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
    ~LList<T>() {}

    //generic function, trying to specialize
    void insert(const T&);
};
```

LinkedList.cpp

```
//definitions of generic insert function
template<typename T>
void LList<T>::insert(const T& newData)
{
    //code
}

//I would like to specialize as follows 
void LList<std::string>insert(const std::string& newData)
{
    //code
}
```

I tried adding another function definition to the Linked List class in the `.h`, as is done for generic function specialization outside of classes:

```
void LList<std::string>::insert(const std::string&);
```

But that just yields 4 new errors, all on that new line:

```
'string': is not a member of 'std'
'void LList<std::string>::insert(const T &)': member function ready defined or declared
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note C++ does not support default-int
syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
```

Is there a way for me to specialize the `insert()` member function similar to specializing templates normally?

Comment: Related: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/)

Comment: Did you actually `#include <string>` anywhere before referring to the type?

Comment: *I would like to specialize as follows* That's not a specialization, that's overloaded member function, that is not declared in the class.

Comment: @KenWhite Unfortunately that question does not have an answer, thus I have added the dup of the dup. LNK2005 is followed by LINK1169.

Comment: @273K: OK. I've removed the comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Useless yes I did, in my .cpp file

Comment: @273K How do I overload the member function correctly?

Comment: @camdenmcgath All is shown in the dups.

Comment: @273K I'm sorry, but what are the dups

Comment: "dup" is "duplicate", already answered question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956164/what-does-dup-mean-in-tasm